# Apache mod_rewrite adding anchor to query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add an anchor to an URL with a query string. The original URL is

`https://example.com/foo?query=123`

It should redirect to

`https://example.com/foo?query=123#anchor`

These are my Rules in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^query=[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$
RewriteRule (.*) /foo?%{QUERY_STRING}#anchor [NC,NE,R=302,L,END]
```

Do you have an idea how to avoid the redirecting loop?

Comment: I added some additional notes (background reading) regarding your current rule to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905401/369434) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have an idea how to avoid the redirecting loop?

This is not possible with a server-side (Apache / `.htaccess`) redirect, without changing the URL-path or query string in some way.

The `#anchor` (or *fragment identifier*) is not passed to the server in the redirected request, so the *same* URL matches your rule and triggers another redirect to append `#anchor`, again and again, etc.

When you request `/foo?query=123`, the request is 302 redirected to `/foo?query=123#anchor` (the rule you've posted already does that). However, the browser only sends `/foo?query=123` (no fragment identifier) back in the redirected request so the process starts over.

The only way to prevent the redirect loop in your "server-side" redirect is to change other elements of the URL in someway that you can then detect in you rule. eg. redirect to `/bar?query=123#anchor` or `/foo?query=123&noredirect=1#anchor` etc.

However, fragment identifiers (`#anchors`) are only used by the client-side script/HTML, so if `#anchor` is required on the URL then this should be added using JavaScript instead.

---

*Aside:* Just a few notes about your existing rule:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo$
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^query=[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$
> RewriteRule (.*) /foo?%{QUERY_STRING}#anchor [NC,NE,R=302,L,END]
> ```

- There's no need to use the `L` *and* `END` flags together. The `L` flag stops the current round of processing and the `END` flag stops all further processing by the rewrite engine. However, when used together with the `R` flag they behave exactly the same - all further processing is stopped regardless of whether you use `L` or `END` flag.
- `query=[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$` - You've used the `\s` (whitespace) shorthand character class - this is superfluous as it will never match here. (Can your query string value actually contain spaces?) The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is %-encoded, so there is never a literal space. Any *spaces* in the requested query string will either be URL encoded as `%20` or `+`.
- The `NC` (`nocase` flag) on the `RewriteRule` directive is superfluous since you are matching "everything" anyway (ie. `.*`). I'd wager this is entirely superfluous anyway, since you are not using the `NC` flag on the preceding condition where it would be required - if at all.
- `(.*)` - in the rule as posted there is no need for the parenthesised subpattern (capturing group), since the backreference is not being used anywhere.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo$` - there's no need for this condition as the URL-path can be performed more efficiently in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([\w-]+\?query=\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1#anchor [L,R,NE]
```